# excel table with c#, format

Tags: c#, excel, format

I'm making an excel table with c#. One of the columns contains the information about a house number. The house number in my program is a string. When this stirng for example is "3-5" it appears as "5.March" in the excel sheet. How can I format this correctly in my c# code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **NumberFormat** property of cell to `string`

```
// Format cell A as text.
cell["A1"].NumberFormat = "@";
```

This might work for you.